# creating a dynamically expanding feed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So what I have in my view atm is just a list of every item in my class. What I want to be able to do is have it only display the first ten or so, and put a button at the bottom that will then load the next ten into the page, and so on. Anyone mind pointing me towards a nice tutorial that will show me how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the functionality you are requesting is similar to "infinite scroll", which appends additional results as you scroll towards the bottom the page. You don't really need a button, unless you want to specifically design it this way.

A nice tutorial on infinite scrolling can be found here: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery